# Visual Studio 2013 C compiling Syntax errors and C2100 illegal indirection error

Tags: c

I've been trying to write some code for a university assignment, but I am having a lot of trouble compiling it. I'm a begginer in C, and in programming in general, and have little experience with finding those errors. After looking at my code for hours on end, I have managed to correct some of them, but there are a few that are quite persistent and I can't pinpoint them. The code is bellow:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define ARRAYLENGTH 20

typedef struct{
char *name;
char *type;
char *value;
}variable;


int main(){
    char calc[10];
    char name1[20];
    char name2[20];
    int amount, i;
    variable *varray;
    int var1, var2;


    printf("How many variables would you like to create? \n");
    scanf("%d", amount);
    varray = malloc(amount * ARRAYLENGTH * sizeof(variable));
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        if (varray[i].name == NULL || varray[i].type == NULL || varray[i].value == NULL){
            printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failed. \n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

You can probably see some declared variables not used in this block of code. They are used in later pieces of the program not seen here.

I have tried googling my problem, and searching for a solution in older questions here, on Stack Overflow, but nothing seems to work for those specific errors, and as such, I decided to ask my own question.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciate it. Please try to simplify the answers a little bit, since, as I mentioned earlier, I am a begginer.

Comment: If you must cast, use `(variable*)`

Comment: u mean variable * not *variable

Comment: That corrects errors C2275 and C2146, but generates a new one:
error C2440 : '=' : cannot convert from 'variable*' to 'variable'

Comment: If you are actually compiling this as C (and not C++), please do not cast the result of `malloc()`.

Comment: I must, actually, cast it. First off, that's how we did it in class, and I'm afraid of having grade defecit if I don't do it, and secondly, it gives me an error if I don't cast it.

Comment: now that you have made corrections please edit the question with the corrected code and the new errors

Comment: @LukeSykpe If the name of your source file ends in `.cpp` then MSVC will be compiling this as C++, not C (in which case, yes, the cast is necessary). Consider changing the tag to c++ if that is the case. Casting the result of `malloc()` is incorrect in C.

Comment: @Iskar Jarak No, it's called Assignment1.c

Comment: When I removed the cast, it gave me an error saying something like " 'void*' cannot be converted to 'variable' "

I didn't feel like it was necessary to mention, since re-adding the cast fixed that one.

Comment: @LukeSykpe then somehow it is still compiling it as C++, despite the apparent file extension. Are you compiling this through visual studio or from the command line?

Comment: Visual Studio's command prompt, using "cl Assignment1.c"

Comment: Remove the `;` in the `#define`

Comment: @LukeSykpe Try using the /Tc option to force compilation as C, then. That cast is incorrect in C.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you very much, that fixed 3/4 errors. Can't believe I actually missed that one. Actually, I didn't have it with a ; to begin with, but added it later, after I encountered a few other errors. It *seemed* to have fixed those errors, but created a few of its own.

Comment: @IskarJarak When you say use /Tc, do you mean instead of cl?

Sorry, I'm kinda new to this. Over in class, we compile using GCC on a solaris server.

Comment: No, I mean as an option to cl. Like `cl /Tc file.c`. Before you do that, though, get rid of the leading `*` when you're assigning the result of `malloc()`, too. Like `varray = malloc(...);` instead of `*varray = malloc(...);` because the latter tries to assign the allocated memory to a `variable` instead of a `variable*`. This was the cause of your `"'void*' cannot be converted to variable"`. Fix that and your error without casting will go away.

Comment: That fixed it alright. Thanks everyone.

One more thing though. Is the check I do to determine if malloc() allocated memory properly correct? Because I'm not too confident about that.

Comment: No, you should do check `varray` straight after the allocation, like `varray = malloc(...);` then `if (NULL == varray) { ... handle failure case }`. Checking fields within array elements won't work if the allocation fails, because the pointer itself (`varray`, that is), will be null.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I had it the way you proposed, at first, and then changed it to how I have it in the code posted above, because I was feeling like it was not correct. Turn out it was fine all along. Thanks for everything :)

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning "varray" value at the current addres, not the address itself, also cast has the star in wrong place and is unneeded:

```
varray = malloc(amount * ARRAYLENGTH * sizeof(variable));
```

Comment: The first one didn't seem to do anything. At least it didn't correct any of the present errors, don't know about what'll happen when I continue with the code.

As for the second, I already corrected it, as people pointed it out in the comments.

Comment: You added a struct tag. With the definition in the question, the type is called `variable`. With your addition, it can be called either `variable` or `struct variable`. My personal preference is to drop the `typedef` and call the type `struct variable`, but just calling it `variable` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Ok, going to correct the answer, I always get confused if the tag is the first or the last name, so I add always both of them :D

Comment: Please take the cast out of this answer.

Comment: ehm...what do you mena @IskarJarak?

Comment: In C (not C++!), you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc(...)`, and OP only added the cast to try and fix another error anyway. `varray = malloc(amount * ARRAYLENGTH * sizeof(variable));` would be preferable to what you have right now.

Comment: Oh, it's pure C, not C++, ok

Answer (score 0):

The compilation errors in your code as posted are:

- `pritnf` should read `printf`.
- There should be a `}` at the end.

There are also some serious logic errors:

- `scanf("%d", amount);` should be `scanf("%d", &amount)`
- either the above should have error checking, or `amount` should be initialized to `0`
- You test `varray[i].name == NULL` before initializing `varray[i].name`. The way to check if allocation failed is to check whether the pointer returned by `malloc` is NULL.

Comment: If you are still having compilation errors then please make sure your question includes the **exact code** you are trying to compile. Do this by copy-pasting, not typing it out.

Comment: Thank you for pointing those out. "pritnf" was actually a mistake I did while converting the text to code for my post. In my actual code, it's fine. The curly bracket at the end is there. This is not the whole main class, and that's why you can't see it in that piece of code.

Comment: @LukeSykpe nobody can tell you why code you didn't post is having errors.

Comment: The part of the code I didn't post didn't have errors, that's the point behind me not posting it. -At least not syntax errors. It might have logical errors, but I'll iron those out when I finish the project.

Comment: @LukeSykpe what problem are you having? You said you are having trouble compiling; I pointed out all the compilation errors in the code that you posted, and then you said the real code didn't actually have those errors.

Comment: I am not having any problems, currently. The problem was with malloc's casting. I thank you for pointing out the logic errors, which I did correct. All I said was the 2 syntax errors you pointed out weren't actual errors, just typos of mine while posting the question, and are not wrong in the actual code.

The code has now compiled properly. Well, almost, it gets stuck as an "object", and can't become an executable yet, but that's only because it is incomplete.